# recaptcha not allowing login on localhost

Tags: captcha

hi Not sure if this is specifically a Drupal question but I'll try it here first.

I am using Google recaptcha on my site, I set it up while the site was already online. but now I'm trying to make some changes I've backedup and downloaded my site to a localhost dev machine. now when I use this site I get:
"Google reCAPTCHA does not accept this submission. Try again please, or contact to Site support services."

its a bit frustrating and the only method I can think of is to remove this tool on the website, then dump the DB for my local version.

Anyone know another way around this, specifically to get it working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Google, your production site is not the same, as your devel one. But you can disable modules using [drush](http://www.drush.org/en/master/), that does not require you to log in.

Comment: ha. and I've got this far without using Drush. Guess its time to learn!